# Find and replace dot with text in column1 using gawk or awk

Tags: gawk

I have a csv as follows

```
1.2kbps,link1,description
1.2mbps,link2,description
```

I would like to Find and replace

a)dot and kbps with 000 in column1

b)dot and mbps with 000000 in column1
 using gawk or awk and output should look like follows

```
12000,link1,description
12000000,link2,description
```

I prefer Gawk but can use awk examples and play with it

Thanks

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have only one digit past the decimal?  Also, the number of 0's in both your examples is wrong.

Comment: A rate of `1.2kbps` should be `1200` (not `12000`, one zero more than needed).

Comment: There is a possibility of 1.24kbps or 1.2345mbps in the data set..I just need the dot to be replaced with correct number of zeroes to normalize the data set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (tested against GNU Awk 3.1.7):

```
awk '{sub(/\./,"");sub(/kbps/,"000");sub(/mbps/,"000000")}1' foo.csv
```

Comment: A rate of 1.2kbps should be 1200, not 12000.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
awk -F, '
         BEGIN{OFS=FS}
         /kbps/{gsub("kbps","",$1);$1=$1*1000};
         /mbps/{gsub("mbps","",$1);$1=$1*1000000}
         1' file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks...Is the Gnuwin32 gawk syntax different than the above?..I am getting syntax error.                                                                                 "awk: '{sub(/\./,);sub(/kbps/,000);sub(/mbps/,000000)}1'
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression"

Comment: @Programmingnewbie Maybe that is a comment to make in the other answer. And, maybe, you should *not* place the command inside "double quotes".